# MockMVC instance not being instantiated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5, mockmvc

I am new to JUnit5 an MockMvc and am struggling to establish basic communication between a test class
and a Controller in a fully developed web application.

The UI is a Spring Boot application built on the MVC pattern. I would like to target one Controller
to prove my setup works and I have been using the MockMVC example in section 4.26.3 in the Spring Bott Reference
as a starting point ([Spring Boot Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment))

When I run my test code I get the following a NullPointerException. Stepping through in debug mode shows me that
when I hit `this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())` the mockMvc
instance is null. It would seem that there is an issue building MockMvc but does not provide any further information.
This is puzzling because the code is almost identical to the example provided:

```
@WebMvcTest([my controller class]) 
public class TestController {
  
  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  
  @MockBeans for Services
    
  @Test
  public void testConfig() {}
  
  @Test
  public void testGet() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}
```

I am using version 5.7.1 of the junit jupiter engine. I am sorry I cannot post the whole pom as it is full of proprietory
information. I am also using Java 8 and Spring boot start test version 2.2.0.RELEASE.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions as towhat I may have missed. Thanks.

Comment: THe autowired field cannot be `null`. If it is `null` it isn't run with the correct runner. SO I suspect that ou are using the wrong `@Test` annotation, the one from JUnit5 instead of Junit4. Also when using Spring Boot 2.2.0 (I would suggest to upgrade) you might want to use the documentation belonging to that version as well (you are linking to the current documentation which is, for now, 2.4.4).

Comment: M.Deinum thank you for your insight. I have double checked the code and the @Test annotations definitely come from JUnit5 - which is what I intended. I also went back to the 2.2.0 docs and the MockMvc example there is the same as the current version. So, it would seem something else is causing the MockMVC instantiation to fail and I need to find a way of narrowing it down.

Comment: The point is if autowiring would fail you would get an exception during startup that the field couldn't be autowired. If the tests run and the field is `null` the test is either not run by the Test Context Framework or you aren't showing your actual code which is probably different from this.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that the exception is telling me why the test can't be run. What I am not seeing is any indication as to why the initialization of MockMvc failed. It's as if the context is being built. I think that's what I need to dig into. Thanks